# Remove breadcrumbs if "home" in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the breadcrumbs function in my header.php. I don't want to the breadcrumbs to appear on my homepage but all other pages I want it to appear. Please help in how I can achieve this.

The function to display the breadcrumbs in the header is:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs" class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php breadcrumb_trail( array(
        'separator' => '&raquo;',
        'before' => '',
        'show_home' => '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .    '/images/breadcrumb-home.png" />',
    ) ); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (! is_home()) {...}`. More info here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference

Comment: @elclanrs why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: It's basic stuff, it's more of a RTFM thing... There's also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, so it's kinda offtopic as well.

Comment: Ok i managed to solve this..

I replaced the body tag of my header with

`<body<?php if(! is_home()) echo ' id="homepage"';?>>`

and this to my css

`body#homepage#breadcrumbs {visibility: hidden;}` meaning that if the current page is the homepage, the breadcrumbs will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to solve this..

I replaced the body tag of my header with

`<body<?php if(! is_home()) echo ' id="homepage"';?>>`

and this to my css

`body#homepage#breadcrumbs {visibility: hidden;}`meaning that if the current page is the homepage, the breadcrumbs will not be shown.