# How to remove breadcrumbs if “home” in wordpress static front page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I found this one [Remove breadcrumbs if "home" in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342764/remove-breadcrumbs-if-home-in-wordpress) 
but sadly not working for me

```
<body<?php if(! is_home()) echo ' id="homepage"';?>>
```

in header.php

```
body#homepage#breadcrumbs {visibility: hidden;}
```

and added in style.css

Comment: Without the structure of your html it's quite hard to tell. It could be that your breadcrumbs are not in a div with id breadcrumbs. Or something else. Please show the breadcrumbs part of html.

Comment: I am using free Accelerate theme and Breadcrumb Trail plugin

Comment: Next time just add the rendered html of the breadcrumbs. It's easier than to look it up through the plugin.

Comment: Thanks @ all and special  thanks to @  TeeDeJee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change your css to this. Because Breadcrumb Trail uses a class of breadcrumbs and not an id.

```
body#homepage .breadcrumbs
```

Have you tried using `is_frontpage()` instead of `is_home()` ?
Do you realize that at the moment you are adding homepage id to all pages which are not the "home" page? Don't use the `!` in your if.

```
<body<?php if(is_frontpage()) echo ' id="homepage"';?>>
```

- blog postspage = frontpage

  On the site front page:

  - is_front_page() will return TRUE
  - is_home() will return TRUE
- static page = frontpage

  - On the page assigned to display the site front page:

    - is_front_page() will return TRUE
    - is_home() will return FALSE
  - On the page assigned to display the blog posts index:

    - is_front_page() will return FALSE
    - is_home() will return TRUE

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend.but does not work for me :(

Comment: @VikramChandran I updated the css code. Can you try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try separating the #breadcrumbs.

In the CSS:

```
body#homepage #breadcrumbs {visibility: hidden;}
```

The code you posted refers to a body element with an ID breadcrumbs. What you need to target is an element with #breadcrumbs ID, that is inside a body with #homepage ID.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the body has .home class in Wordpress by default.

So you can achieve it without the PHP part.

```
body.home #breadcrumbs{display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend.but does not work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it using [body_class()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

And then in the css if it's home page you can use

```
body.home #breadcrumbs { visibility: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Update - it's `.breadcrumbs` not `#breadcrumbs`:

```
body#homepage .breadcrumbs { visibility: hidden; }
```

PHP:

```
<body<?php if(is_home()) echo ' id="homepage"';?>>
```

In your header.php code, the `!` means NOT, therefore you're saying:

> if NOT homepage, add id "homepage"

Which is the opposite of what you want.

Also note that `visibility:hidden` will hide the element but preserve its space in the layout.. if you want to hide the element and its space you can use `display:none` instead.

As @Eric-Mitijans explained, you have to add a space between `body#homepage` and `#breadcrumbs` otherwise you'd target a body tag with 2 IDs which is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the if condition with home page id.